# GRASS v.clean error in generating output layers

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to run v.clean through GRASS 7.6.1 using QGIS 3.10 and Python 3.7 on a line shapefile. I have tried with the output both saving to a file location and as a temporary file, and the error is the same.

Input Parameters:

```
{ '-b' : False, '-c' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 
'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 2, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 
'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 
'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'error' : 
'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'input' : 'C:/file.shp', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'threshold' : 
'1', 'tool' : [1], 'type' : [1] }
```

Error message:

```
File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 177
file=sys.stderr)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Press any key to continue . . .
File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 177
file=sys.stderr)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Press any key to continue . . .
Execution completed in 2.32 seconds
Results:
{'error': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>,
'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}
```

The closest answer I could find was an issue with using Python 2 instead of 3, but I am definitely using Python 3.7. I have had issues with that in the past, and made sure to run this both with my regular file names and renaming the path for 2.7 to be sure it's not accidentally using Python 2.

Comment: Did you try with grass 7.8? https://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/

Comment: @Victor I don't know how to run 7.8 through QGIS

Comment: Can you include the output from the _Python Console_ in QGIS for `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used GRASS before, but the python error message looks familiar, at times when I've used incompatible scripts (e.g. something written for 2.x, but run in 3.x, or vice-versa). I know you've mentioned the discrepancy in your post, but have you tried running the same operation using 2.x? The python installation may have added env variables that automatically run a particular python installation from one of the install directories (i.e. 2.x install or 3.x install). You may have to explicitly include the full path to the python version you'd like to target (e.g. c:\Python27\python.exe).

Comment: Running in 2.7 worked - had to force 2.7 by changing the path to 3.7 and then it worked to run through QGIS.